# how to call a view in one app to a template in another app in django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am new to Django and I am doing a project which has multiple functionalities. I am planning to break down it into smaller ones. So what I planned to do is to have all the template in main.html and functions into different small apps.

```
--main_app
  --templates
    --main.html
--app_1
  --app1_view.py
--app_2
  --app2_view.py
```

So my problem is how can I link the main.html templates with the different logic I have written in the views of different apps. Can anyone point me to proper documents or examples. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The way I would model my static files is as follows:

```
--main_app
  --templates
    -- main_app
      -- main.html
      -- other.html
      -- some_other.html
  --static
    -- main_app
      --css
      --js
      --images
```

If you keep your directory structure like this. Then you can easily refer to your main.html in any view as 
**main_app/main.html**

This sounds wierd, but doing it this way is the recommended django way. now you can easily copy the whole app and paste it in another project without worrying about static files management.

Comment: My question is not how to structure the static files. What I want is how to link a view in one app to an HTML in another app

Comment: you simply have to use main_app/main.html in your view, no matter which app it is present in, provided you have the directory structure mentioned above.

Comment: I am trying to emphasis on the fact that inside templates directory there should be another directory with app name. then all you have to do, to refer that template is app_name/template_name

Answer (score -1):

Django recommends a proper way to structure templates. Its a good practise to follow the recommended method by the framework itself. When you develop software, there's a set of **'best practises'** which you should follow. These 'best practises' makes your code perfect, easily portable & easily readable. So always follow the best practises.

Now for your question, the best practise is to keep all 'templates' related to a particular Django app inside that specific apps folder.

**Here is a scenario:**

You're building a blog. And you've blog posts as an 'app' with name 'posts'. Now all your templates which handle blog posts like 'blog_post_details' (which lists complete details of a single blog post), 'blog_posts_home' (which collects and lists all recent blog posts), 'category_blog_posts' (which lists all category specific blog posts) etc. - all such templates regarding a blog post should be created inside the app folder named 'posts'.

**And here's how to do it:**

Create a folder named 'templates' inside the app named 'posts' 
Now inside this 'templates' folder create another folder named 'posts'

Now create all your HTML files inside this sub folder named 'posts' (which is inside the templates folder).

**How to access:**

From anywhere in your app or even from another app, you can access the templates by writing 'posts/template_name.html'

If you've a template named 'post_detail.html' saved inside the 'posts' folder. here's how you access it.

Inside the any app:

```
def details(request):
return render(request, 'posts/post_details.html')
```

I hope you got the idea. Always follow best practises.